# How to restore a "contained" database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, contained-database

I recently tried to restore to my local development SQL Server a backup from a network instance.  To my surprised I received the following error message:

> Msg 12824, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The sp_configure value 'contained
>   database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to restore a
>   contained database.  You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the
>   value_in_use. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 RESTORE DATABASE is
>   terminating abnormally.

What steps must I follow to successfully restore the database?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? The error is pretty clear about a resolution, did you try setting the `contained database authentication` value to 1 like it said to?

Comment: I think this is a valid question, if you are trying to restore a Azure Sql Database .bacpac file, into your local instance - you get this error. The answer is valid in fixing this.

Comment: @RalphWillgoss do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @MichaelGreen Its been a while but I believe the accepted answer is correct for this context.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In order to restore a contained database into a different instance of sql server, in this case my local server, the "**Enable Contained Databases**" property must be set to **True**.

You can do this from management studio:

1. Right-Click on the server instance, select *Properties*
2. Select *Advanced* page, set  under **Containment** the property value to **True**
3. Proceed to restore the database backup.
4. `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::ReplaceThisWithYourDatabaseName TO ReplaceThisWithLeastPrivilegeUser;`

Here are the script lines I actually used for enabling/disabling containment:

```
-- Enable "contained database authentication"
EXEC sp_configure 'contained', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

-- Disable "contained database authentication"
EXEC sp_configure 'contained', 0;
-- Force disabling of "contained database authentication"
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```

For additional information please refer to:
http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/protectionfromrestoringabackupofacontaineddatabase

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried doing what the error is describing?

```
USE master
GO
sp_configure 'show   advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'CONTAINED DATABASE AUTHENTICATION', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'show   advanced options', 0 
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```